# How can you find all documents that match the last element of an array field with a given query value in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Collection with a structure similar to:

```
type Products {
       productid: String
       owners: [String]
}
```

In my query, I'm inputting a value `user`. I need to retrieve all documents that match the last element in `owners`, hopefully using find. I've tried `Products.find({ "$owners.-1": user })`
with no luck so far

Is there any way to access the last element of this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean to get only the documents where passed in `user` value is the last element in `owners` array from `Products` collection, then try this :

```
var user = 'myname';    
Products.find( { $expr: {$eq : [{ $arrayElemAt: [ '$owners', -1 ] }, user]} })
```

**Collection Data :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f82b0d02e05b694b48b9d"),
    "productid" : "1",
    "owners" : [ 
        "others", 
        "myname"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f84d3d02e05b694b4cbe0"),
    "productid" : "2",
    "owners" : [ 
        "others", 
        "myname", 
        "anothername"
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f84e2d02e05b694b4cee2"),
    "productid" : "3",
    "owners" : [ 
        "myname", 
        "anothername"
    ]
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f84ebd02e05b694b4d0d0"),
    "productid" : "4",
    "owners" : [ 
        "myname"
    ]
}
```

**Result :**

```
 /** Only "productid" : "1" & "productid" : "4" are returned */
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f82b0d02e05b694b48b9d"),
    "productid" : "1",
    "owners" : [ 
        "others", 
        "myname"
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e1f84ebd02e05b694b4d0d0"),
    "productid" : "4",
    "owners" : [ 
        "myname"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed and it worked wonderfully!!

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you the last element in the owners list.

```
db.Products.find( {}, { owners: { $slice: -1 } } );
```